# 「12a345a67.8」から正規表現で、「12」と「345a67.8」をキャプチャ取得したい

Tags: 正規表現

**対象**

```
12a345a67.8
90a123a45
67.8a901a23.4
```

---

**前提条件**
・aの個数は「0」か「2」
・aが「0」の場合は何も処理しない

---

**やりたいこと**
・上記のような文字列がある時、`「最初のaまで」と「それ以降」`、もしくは、`「最初のaまで」「2番目のaまで」「それ以降」`をそれぞれ分離してキャプチャ取得したい

**12a345a67.8の場合**
・下記何れかの分離方式でキャプチャ取得したい
・`「12」「345a67.8」`
・`「12a」「345a67.8」`
・`「12」「345」「67.8」`
・`「12a」「345a」「67.8」`

---

**試したこと**
・最初のaまでキャプチャ取得

```
^(.*?)a
```

Comment: 使用する言語を指定していただいた方が、より適切な回答ができると思います。

Comment: Windowsソフトウェアで正規表現を試してみたいと思い、質問しました

Comment: [詳説 正規表現](https://www.oreilly.co.jp/books/9784873113593/)を一読されることをお勧めします。正規表現エンジン毎に使用可能な機能が異なりますし、表現も異なります。ですのでエンジンを指定されない質問は回答に困ります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

言語依存の低い記述としては

```
^([^a]+a)([^a]+a)?(.+)$
```

でしょうか。２番目の`a`までの部分について`?`とすることでマッチする場合は取り込み、しない場合は通過し「それ以降」に回すことができます。

この辺り、質問文が曖昧なので何を求めているのかうまく読み取れません。`a`が確実に２つ以上存在するのか１つの場合にも対処したいとしているのか、それとも技術的にハードルが高いと感じ２つ目以降の`a`を気にしなくてもよいと言っているのか、とか。`a`が３個以上存在する場合にはどうふるまってほしいのか、とか。

---

追記

> - aの個数は「0」か「2」
> - aが「0」の場合は何も処理しない

とのことですので、

```
^([^a]+)a(.+)$          // 「12」「345a67.8」
^([^a]+a)(.+)$          // 「12a」「345a67.8」
^([^a]+)a([^a]+)a(.+)$  // 「12」「345」「67.8」
^([^a]+a)([^a]+a)(.+)$  // 「12a」「345a」「67.8」
```

で十分でした。実は「何も処理しない」という前提条件もあいまいで、マッチに失敗してほしいのか、それとも全体を「最初のaまで」もしくは「それ以降」として扱ってほしいのか、解釈が分かれます。上記回答は「マッチしない」動作となります。

Comment: 質問内容が曖昧だったため、前提条件追記しました

Answer (score 2):

`^(.*?)a(.*)$`

とすれば、`\1`で最初のaまでが、`\2`最初のa以降が取得できると思います。
実装するなら、再帰的に実行すれば2番目以降のaについてもa以前、a以降が取得できると思います。

1つの正規表現でも、複数のaに対してmatchさせることは可能だと思うんですが...正規表現の処理系に依存すると思うので、とりあえずここまでで。

Comment: なるほど。正規表現の内容が難しくなるほど、「正規表現の処理系に依存する」わけですね。参考になりました

Comment: いや、もっぱら使われている正規表現と言われている物は拡張仕様なんです。拡張仕様なんで、実装によって解釈が異なっている場合があり、全ての正規表現を扱うclassやプログラムで動くとは限らないんです。で、今回の要件に合う正規表現を一発で書こうとすると、そういう部分に抵触しそうだなぁ...と思ったので回答のような書き方にさせてもらいました。実行する環境などを記載されれば、もっと良い回答が付く可能性もあると思いますよ。

Comment: 条件が更新されてますね。aの数が0 or 2であれば、1発で処理することは可能ですね。上記のコメントはaが0回以上登場する前提で書いてます。

Answer (score 1):

Pythonで実装してみました。

- 入力: 12a345a67.8
- 出力: 12, 345, 67.8

https://ideone.com/WKF37V

```
import re

SRCSTR = "12a345a67.8"
PATN = r"[^\sa,]+"
res = re.findall(PATN, SRCSTR)

for elem in res:
    print(elem)
```

結果

```
12
345
67.8
```

また、
https://www.debuggex.com/#cheatsheet
にて
- 言語Pythonの下のボックスに「[^\sa,]+」を
- その下(Result)に「12a345a67.8」を
入力して確認しました。
( https://www.debuggex.com/r/bjIEfhzPYHXraF_P )

12a345a67.8a9012
なども対応可能です。

参考: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808707/python-find-substrings-based-on-a-delimiter