# 秀丸エディタで、「CSVのN列目のデータ」に対してのみ「正規表現置換処理」したい

Tags: 正規表現

**やりたいこと**
・秀丸エディタで、「CSVの9列目のデータ」に対してのみ[リンク先の正規表現置換処理](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/38411/12a345a67-8-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E6%AD%A3%E8%A6%8F%E8%A1%A8%E7%8F%BE%E3%81%A7-12-%E3%81%A8-345a67-8-%E3%82%92%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%97%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)したい
※CSVは「,」区切り

---

**分からないこと**
・「CSVのN列目のデータだけ」を、正規表現で取得する方法
※「CSVのN列目までのデータ」ではなく「CSVのN列目のデータのみ」が対象

---

**試したこと**
・[このページに記載されている内容](http://monaski.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/06/21/141427)で、「CSVのN列目のデータだけ」を取得できたのですが、正規表現のキャプチャ置換を既に使用しているため、そこからさらに(エディタでは)正規表現が出来ません
・置換前の正規表現だけで、「CSVのN列目のデータのみ」を取得する方法はあるでしょうか？

Comment: 秀丸ではないですが、gPadというエディタでは、CSVモードで「列選択」しつつ、正規表現で「選択した範囲のみ」を検索することが可能です。

Comment: 今更ですが、メニュー単独の置換ではなく、マクロで何とかしようという記事がありました。[秀丸マクロで列ごとに一括置換したい](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/9012866.html)

Answer (score 1):

CSVではダブルクォートで囲めばカンマや改行も使えますし、ダブルクォート自体は２文字連続で表現できるので、正規表現だけで対応するのはかなり難しいのではないでしょうか。（個人的には無理）
ダブルクォートの使用が無い前提であれば、先出の例でも行けると思いますが。

Answer (score 0):

秀丸で結果は確認できていませんが、
例えば5列目の頭に●を追加する場合、下記でどうでしょうか。

```
・検索文字列
^((?:[^,]*,){4})([^,]*)(,|$)

・置換文字列
\1●\2\3
```

上記の正規表現は、すべての行の5列目がヒットするため、
5列目に含まれるfooだけをヒットさせてbarに置換したい場合は、
下記のようにすれば良いでしょう。

```
・検索文字列
^((?:[^,]*,){4}[^,]*)(foo)([^,]*?,|$)

・置換文字列
\1bar\3
```